# Extending an object multiple times with the same module in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Given a class `Klass` and an instance `k` of this class:

```
class Klass
  def hello
    'Hello'
  end
end

k = Klass.new
k.hello        #=> "Hello"
```

I can `extend` this instance with a module to add methods to this specific instance without altering the whole class (i.e. all instances):

```
module Mod
  def hello
    "#{super}, World!"
  end
end

k.extend(Mod)
k.hello        #=> "Hello, World!"
```

But what happens if I extend `k` multiple times with the same module?

```
k.extend(Mod)
k.extend(Mod)
k.extend(Mod)
k.hello        #=> "Hello, World!"
```

Are the subsequent calls ignored or is the object extended multiple times?

To put it another way: is it "safe" to extend an object multiple times?

Comment: Is that different from doing it on a class, or doing `include`/`prepend`?

Comment: @sawa it's probably the same with classes, but I'm woking with instances in my code.

Comment: Also in your example you are extending with the same module multiple times which @sawa has show you a way to check for through ancestry. That being said if you extend using different modules that have the same method names the most recent extension's method will be used and you will not be able to protect against this.

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah, in my use case it's always the same module. I'm traversing a linked object structure within a test and I currently call `obj.extend(Mod).helper_method` without knowing if `obj` was already extended.

Comment: @engineersmnky In my understanding, when there is already the same module within the ancestors, inclusion/extension has no effect. This is a special case. I don't think the last extension takes effect. It should be the first one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the subsequent calls are ignored (unless you have something deeper in mind). The following result shows `Mod` only once in the ancestor list.

```
class Klass; end
module Mod; end
k = Klass.new
k.extend(Mod)
k.extend(Mod)
k.extend(Mod)
k.singleton_class.ancestors
# => [#<Class:#<Klass:0x007f7787ef7558>>, Mod, Klass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 7):

sawa [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199084/477037) the actual question, but this could be relevant, too. Although the `Mod` is added only once to the object's (singleton class') ancestors, the [`extended`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Module.html#method-i-extended) callback is called every time:

```
class Klass
end

module Mod
  def self.extended(mod)
    puts "#{self} extended in #{mod}"
  end
end

k = Klass.new
k.extend(Mod)
#=> "Mod extended in #<Klass:0x007fabbb029450>"
k.extend(Mod)
#=> "Mod extended in #<Klass:0x007fabbb029450>"
k.extend(Mod)
#=> "Mod extended in #<Klass:0x007fabbb029450>"
```

Comment: I see. Do depending on what you put in it, it may not be safe.